# Need help to understand Java Bytecode Instruction

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, jpl

I'm trying to do static analysis of bytecode in Prolog. I'm using the bcel library to get instruction list from a MethodGen. For aload_0, I get
`0:aload_0[42](1)`

I understand `aload_0` is meant to load 0th Local variable. But I'm having a hard time understanding the next bits i.e `[42](1)`. It's also there for other instructions, for eg:

```
invokespecial[183](3) 8
return[177](1)
```

Can someone please explain what are those?. Would highly appreciate it!

Comment: The normal way of using a Java API, is to query the object properties via the class members, whose names are usually self-explanatory, rather than doing guesswork about the format of the `toString()` output. Besides that, [it is documented](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/Instruction.html#toString-boolean-): `Long output format: <name of opcode> "["<opcode number>"]" "("<length of instruction>")"`

Comment: @Holger Thank you for enlightening me.I had checked the documentation as I claimed and got the answer, just forgot to mark it answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`42` is the opcode for `aload_0`. 
`183` is the opcode for `invokespecial`. `177` is return and so on. The `8` after invokespecial is probably the 16 bit constant pool index that the instruction uses.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-7.html

Comment: Note that the OP failed to do correct formatting, the String actually is `invokespecial[183](3) 8`, which matches [its documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/CPInstruction.html#toString-boolean-): `Long output format: <name of opcode> "["<opcode number>"]" "("<length of instruction>")" "<"< constant pool index>">"`, so your guess is right, but the OP should read the documentation instead of asking us for guesses…